# CSS NavBar not in Place

Tags: html, css

This will probably be a dumb question to ask you guys but I'm fairly new so please bear with me as I am willing to learn.

My problem goes like this, https://alphavirginis.github.io the navigation bar seems to be fine at the landing page, but when you go to the about it seems to have shifted left or if I tried to fix it it'll go to right. I'm quite new to web dev so I'm asking for your help. Thanks!

Here's the github repo https://github.com/AlphaVirginis/AlphaVirginis.github.io

Comment: it seems that when you go to the about page the navigation loses the propriety `text-align: center`

Comment: why don't you give `text-align: center` to the .navigation class in css ?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought it would be better actually giving the link site so it would be complete. I'll do it correctly next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate `.navigation` and `.box`, `.right` than your markup will be like this.

```
<div class="navigation">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="about2.html">About</a>
  <a href="works.html">Works</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</div>
<!-- Navigation Ends Here -->
```

than change some css

```
.navigation {
  text-align: center; // Added
}
```

than wrap two boxes `.box` and `.right` in one wrapper say `.box-wrapper`

```
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
          <img src="img/Lelouch.jpg" alt="" class="box-img">
          <h1> Lelouch Lamperouge </h1>
          <h5> Web Developer - Software Developer </h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores sequi ad suscipit, iure soluta cumque animi, quos rem repellat, nemo voluptatibus libero beatae distinctio! Laboriosam, ducimus, quis? Error, quia dignissimos.</p>
        </div>

    <div style="padding-top: 10px"></div> <!-- Prevenets Margin collapse -->

      <div class="right">
        <img src="img/Lelouch.jpg" alt="" class="box-img">
        <h1>  Lelouch Lamperouge </h1>
        <h5>Web Developer - Software Developer<!--5--></h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores sequi ad suscipit, iure soluta cumque animi, quos rem repellat, nemo voluptatibus libero beatae distinctio! Laboriosam, ducimus, quis? Error, quia dignissimos.</p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- box-wrapper Ends Here -->
```

set the width of `.box-wrapper` as per your requirement

```
.box-wrapper::before, .box-wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1170px; // change as per your requirement
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: If I may ask, what do the .box-wrapper do?

Comment: It will wrap those two boxes and separate those from the navbar so your layout will not break @Jerome

Comment: Finally got it working! Thanks! The thing is the class box and right doesn't seem to align from each other. Right seems to be lower compared to the box.

Comment: Welcome :) @Jerome

Comment: if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

.navigation in the about page you have to give text-align:center css.
It Would solve the problem.